# Extracting string after and before a character '-' or '<' using Sql Query

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have table with one column 'UDF_WorkLocation_6' which contain string.Please Review following table.

```
UDF_WorkLocation_6
MUMBAI - Maharastra<6>
AHMEDABAD - Gujarat<1>
MUMBAI - Maharastra<6>
CHANDIGARH - Chandigarh<34>
NULL
DELHI - Delhi<42>
NULL
INDORE - Madhya Pradesh<56>
```

Here it is column name 'UDF_WorkLocation_6' which contain string in table such as 'INDORE - Madhya Pradesh<56>'.

I want split string from '-' then show output into two columns,In First Column getting string before '-' like 'INDORE' from 'INDORE - Madhya Pradesh<56>' string & second column getting string  after '-' and also remove charter after '<'this like Madhya Pradesh from 'INDORE - Madhya Pradesh<56>'.

So output in table like,

```
**Output Table**

 Column1    Column2 
 MUMBAI      Maharastra
 AHMEDABAD   Gujarat
 MUMBAI      Maharastra
 CHANDIGARH  Chandigarh
 NULL        NULL
 DELHI       Delhi
 NULL        NULL
```

**I have tried to prepared query for split string.**

For instant, string is 'MUMBAI - Maharastra<6> ' and got output for second column like 'Maharastra<6>' using below sql query

```
SELECT LTRIM(SUBSTRING(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, CHARINDEX('-',
        AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) + 2, 100))
```

But i also want two remove charters after '<' this and query for getting string 'MUMBAI' in first column.

Can anyone please help me to prepared query without split function?

Answer (score 1):

The `LEFT` and `RIGHT` functions are helpful for this kind of parsing. They only return X number of characters from that side of a `VARCHAR` like so:

```
SELECT RTRIM(LEFT(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - 1)) AS Column1,  
LEFT(LTRIM(RIGHT(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, LEN(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6))), CHARINDEX('<',LTRIM(RIGHT(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, LEN(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6)))) - 1) AS Column2
```

As you can see, combined with `CHARINDEX` to locate the - in both cases, and `LTRIM` and `RTRIM` to remove any unneeded whitespace.

In the second case you need to apply the `LEFT` function on top of your output from the `RIGHT` function to do one more search and removal of the ending .

Also here's a more formatted version of the stacked functions above that I find more readable if you prefer:

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM
    (
        LEFT
        (
            AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, 
            CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - 1
        )
    ) AS Column1,  
    LEFT
    (
        LTRIM
        (
            RIGHT
            (
                AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, 
                LEN(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6)
            )
        ), 
        CHARINDEX
        (
            '<',
            LTRIM
            (
                RIGHT
                (
                    AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6, 
                    LEN(AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6) - CHARINDEX('-', AccountMasterUDF.UDF_WorkLocation_6)
                )
            )
        ) - 1
    ) AS Column2
```